# Convergence and asymptotic distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Here is the problem I've been working on for a while now:

Let $X_1,..., X_n$ be a random sample of size n from a binomial distribution with pdf $f(x|p)=C^m_xp^x(1-p)^{m-x}$, where $m \in Z^+$ and $p\in(0,1)$. Find: a. The UMVUE for p. b. Show that the estimator in (a) converges in probability to p as n → ∞.
(c) Establish both the asymptotic and the exact distribution of the estimator in (a).

I found that the UMVUE for p is $Y=\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i$. Then I said that by the WLLN we know that $\bar{X}$ converges in probability to $mp$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Further, we know that Y is a function of $\bar{X}$, thus, Y converges in probability to p as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

For part (c) this is what I have so far: By CLT we know that $\frac{\bar{X}-mp}{\frac{\sqrt{mp(1-p)}}{\sqrt{n}}} \rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution. Rearranging the expression we get: $\frac{Y-p}{\frac{m\sqrt{mp(1-p)}}{\sqrt{n}}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$, so $Y\rightarrow N(p,\frac{m^3p(1-p)}{n})$ in distribution. I am not sure if this is correct since I don't have a good understanding of asymptotic distribution... nor how to find exact distribution of an estimator. If somebody could give me some detailed help with it I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is something wrong since $m$ does not appear in your work at all. (Be careful, the $X_i$ are themselves binomial random variables; they are not Bernoulli random variables.)

Comment: I see. Should the statistic be then $Y=\frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$?

Comment: @murph I think you meant $\displaystyle\frac1n \frac1m \sum_{i = 1}^m X_i$

Comment: You are right Lee David Chung Lin. I edited my response. However, I'm still not sure how to continue with answering point c.